# Use of preposition With

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions

> Apart from the obvious toll the pandemic has taken on public health, **with** lives lost and health care facilities stretched to breaking point, there have been alarming ramifications for children in USA.

What is the meaning of **with** in the above sentence? And what is the meaning of "**with lives lost and health care facilities stretched to breaking point"** as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

> Apart from the obvious toll the pandemic has taken on public health, with lives lost and health care facilities stretched to breaking point, there have been alarming ramifications for children in USA.

Here the prepositional phrase *with lives lost and health care facilities stretched to breaking point* is parenthetical: it is to be understood as explanation of the prepositional phrase *Apart from the obvious toll the pandemic has taken on public health.*

So basically the writer is saying something to this effect

> Apart from the obvious toll the pandemic has taken on public health in which lives were lost and health care facilities were stretched to breaking point, there have been alarming ramifications for children in USA.

**with** used in the sense as above means:

> Used as a function word to indicate close association: *With the advent of rockets, the Space Age began.*

[American Heritage Dictionary]

I have reservations, however, about tying together two prepositional phrases like that with the main element in a sentence— for, the meaning though understood, the syntax is somewhat compromised.